# The following Json Format how can filter and display TagNames(without duplicates) and once Click Tag Name it Displays related Names?

Tags: ios, json, swift

The following Json Format how can filter and display TagNames(without duplicates) and once Click Tag Name it Displays related Names using iOS Swift?
Here is the [JSON Code Link](http://beta.json-generator.com/api/json/get/4JqdJ2PD7)

```
[
    {
        "Tags": [
            {
                "TagName": "Engineering"
            }
        ],
        "Name": "Sathya Tech",
        "ID": 201
    },
    {
        "Tags": [
            {
                "TagName": "Infrastructure"
            }
        ],
        "Name": "Naresh Tech",
        "ID": 202
    },
    {
        "Tags": [
            {
                "TagName": "Security"
            },
            {
                "TagName": "Infrastructure"
            }
        ],
        "Name": "Durga Tech",
        "ID": 203
    },
    {
        "Tags": [
            {
                "TagName": "Infrastructure"
            },
            {
                "TagName": "Engineering"
            },
            {
                "TagName": "Security"
            }
        ],
        "Name": "Intee",
        "ID": 204
    },
    {
        "Tags": [
            {
                "$id": 13,
                "$db": ""
            }
        ],
        "Name": "Micro maxi",
        "ID": 205
    },
    {
        "Tags": [
            {
                "TagName": "Analytics"
            }
        ],
        "Name": "Iphono",
        "ID": 206
    },
    {
        "Tags": [
            {
                "TagName": "Engineering"
            }
        ],
        "Name": "Andro",
        "ID": 207
    },
    {
        "Tags": [
            {
                "TagName": "Security"
            },
            {
                "TagName": "Cloud"
            }
        ],
        "Name": "Samu",
        "ID": 208
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks, Okay but I want sample code for filter duplicates and display tag name and, click tag name how to get related Names

Comment: Reading and parsing JSON is pretty easy, it's a very simple text format. Don't you want to learn something? That's a pity. Believe me, *programming* an app is much more fun than *copying&pasting* an app.